# Unable to store tweets in an sql database

Tags: sql, json, twitter

Good morning,

I'm trying to write a short script in php which connect to the twitter API, download the tweets and store them into an sql database.
I'm using the 1.1 version of twitter API with TwitterOauth by Abraham

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret,$access_token,$access_token_secret);
$tweet = $connection->get(
    'search/tweets',
    array("q" => "rome", "lang" => "it")
    );
$jsonData = json_decode($tweet);
```

Using this code, the script succesfully connects to the twitter api, but the $jsonData created with json_decode is empty. I'd like to know why is this happening and if $tweet is in json format.

Comment: put a `var_dump($tweet);` before the `$jsonData = ..` line.

Answer (score 0):

var_dump() helps me a lot to give me information about a variabile.
In my project I have to manage some information in php an put in an sql table.
The  query I post store in $tweet a "tweet object" so I encode this object in json an then decode it in php. My code it's this:

$tweets = $connection->get(
    'search/tweets',
    array("q" => "florence", "count" => 500)
    );

$jsonData = json_encode($tweets);

$pData = json_decode($jsonData);

Now $pData contains the info I need in php.